# How to increase the number of projects a single visa card can cover in firebase

Tags: firebase

Recently, I attempted to apply a visa card to another project of mine in firebase, only to be told that the number of projects I can have on the visa card is exceeded. I only applied it to 4 or 5 other projects. Is there a way I can increase the number of projects on single visa card?

Comment: contact firebase support for this. they maybe able to help you https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: I think I have done that. Your information was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Each user can have only a limited number of projects on the free plan. You should be able to have an unlimited number of projects on a paid plan though.

If you've reached the limit on the number of projects, you can [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) and request that they increase the limit.